# Stop terminal command (CTRL + Z)

Tags: java, macos

I have a terminal command which is shown below.

`instruments -t Activity -D /Users/admin/Desktop/woah.trace -w 878dbd88101f2db8d85ddc8e7ecbc68e45e9f9e7`

This command executes indefinitely, collecting instrument data and the way to end the execution in the terminal is by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

I can run my command via Java using process (`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`) and it works fine.

I just don't know how to stop the execution. Is there a special parameter to replace <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a special parameter to replace CTRL+Z in Java?

No there isn't.

What C-z does in a terminal is send a SIGTSTP to the current process; but Java has no binding for `kill(2)`.

The only option you would have to send this signal is find a native binding to ncurses and send the control character...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have never heard of `ncurses` before. Any more info you can give on this?

Comment: Basically it's a tty handling library; ttys are a whole Unix discipline by themselves, so it's impossible to explain in a comment :) If you are interested, look for documentation on termcap and terminfo, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify, you're saying this is impossible to do using just Java?

Comment: Indeed it is; this is a part which is totally OS dependent. Windows doesn't have anything like ttys, for instance. Also, please note that you should be using a `ProcessBuilder` to run commands, not `Runtime.exec()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with the following code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code to kill java application
    }
});
```